# Hmac sha256 base64 and CryptoJS diffrent for nodejs crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cryptojs

Let say we have simple msg and key:

message = 'simple'

private_key = '123456789';
Using that in angular project with CryptoJS:

```
const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('simple', '123456789');
const signatureBase = signature.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

result for me is:

> lvs7rQTe1EDTLAS1GVWWsNG5ZaYVCh9aaYc+NoEunC4=

using that in msg and key in node:

```
var hmacsignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer("123456789", "base64"))
.update("simple")
.digest()
.toString('base64');
```

result is:

> nYu2PGqfRDWnHbT649q0gc+7DcIq8iwcwHAQQa5T2HY=

Can you tell me which one is correct and how to get same thing is angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In browser string encoding usually is UTF-8, so use UTF-8 as string encoding should fix it. BTW, you should explicitly set string encoding in both side to make sure you will get same result.

```
var hmacsignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from('123456789', 'utf8'))
.update("simple")
.digest()
.toString('base64');
```

And `new Buffer(string)` is deprecated, use `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])` if you can.